# Delete a line and its previous line from file

Tags: python

I have the following file:

```
>Line1
Some contents of line 1
>Line2
------Some contents I don't need
>Line3
More content of line 3
```

I try to delete the lines starting with `---` as well as the previous line, which would give as result:

```
>Line1
Some contents of line 1
>Line3
More content of line 3
```

Here is my current code, for the moment I can only delete the lines starting with `---` but not the line which precedes it:

```
with open("test.txt") as f1:
    for lines in f1:
        if lines.startswith("---"):
            pass
        else:
            print(lines)
```

Comment: You are not actually deleting anything here, you are just printing the entire content of a file to the terminal except for lines that start with ---. Is your goal to only print pairs of text following the pattern: >LineX\nSomethingSomething to the terminal? If so, you should think about reading 2 lines at a time before printing anything

Answer (score 1):

You can try this script to not print the line that starts with `---` and the line before it:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f1:
    i = map(str.strip, f1)
    prev_line = next(i)
    for line in i:
        if line.startswith('---'):
            prev_line = next(i, '')
            continue
        print(prev_line)
        prev_line = line
    print(prev_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most readable solution I could come up with.

```py
with open("test.txt") as lines:
    # initial value (relevant for first line only)
    last_line = next(lines)
    last_line_started_with_dashes = False

    for line in lines:
        this_line_starts_with_dashes = line.startswith("---")

        if not (last_line_started_with_dashes or this_line_starts_with_dashes):
            print(last_line)

        # prepare for next iteration
        last_line_started_with_dashes = this_line_starts_with_dashes
        last_line = line
```

Comment: After your edit: You can initialize `last_line` with `last_line = next(lines)` rather than `last_line=""`. I also think it would be better to include `with open("test.txt") as lines:` in the code you show, especially since the variable you call `lines` is not the same as the variable the OP calls `lines`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion :

```py
with open ("test.txt") as f:
   line1 = f.readline()
   while line1:
      line2 = f.readline()
      if not line2.startswith("---"):
         print(line1,"\n",line2)
      line1 = f.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `grouper` function from the [`itertools` Recipes page](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Using that function to iterate the lines from the file in couples, the main code becomes very compact and simple:

```py
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for lines in grouper(f, 2, fillvalue=''):
        if not lines[1].startswith("---"):
            print(*lines, sep='', end='')
```

Which will print with your example file:

```
>Line1
Some contents of line 1
>Line3
More content of line 3
```